# php reconoce "input type file " como string en laravel 6

Tags: html

Quiero obtener una imagen en mi controlador Laravel para luego guardarlo.

Tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
<form action="/employee/blog/add" method="post" class="add_form">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" id="news_image" name="news_image">
    <input type="submit" value="Publicar">
</form>
```

Y este es el código de mi controlador:

```
$ruta = '/image/';

$news_file = $request->news_image;   

if ($request->hasFile('news_image')) {
    $news_file->move(public_path() . $ruta , 'newsphoto'); 
}

return back()->with('status', 'Imagen agregada correctamente');
```

El problema es que nunca entra al `if ($request->hasFile('news_image'))`.

Entonces puse el metodo `move()` fuera del `if` para ver si reconocía el archivo y me sale el siquiente error:

> Call to a member function move() on string

También intenté obtener la imagen de esta forma:

```
$news_file = $request->file('news_image');
```

y me sale el siguiente error.

> Call to a member function move() on null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agrega este atributo a la etiqueta `form`

```
enctype='multipart/form-data'
```

Con esto puedes mandar archivos, de otra forma estarías enviando texto plano.